# Is the range of frequency we hear dependent on the natural frequency of our ear?

Tags: acoustics, biophysics

Is the range of frequency we hear dependent on the [natural frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_frequency) of our ear?

(i guess the question is clear enough. Just writing to meet "quality standards".)

Answer (score 0):

I guess by natural frequency of the ear you mean the frequency which causes higher resonance in the ear, thinking of the ear as a resonant cavity. In which case this is dependent only on the physical shape and mechanical properties of the specific ear we are talking about.

If this is the case, yes, the range of hearing is independent of its natural frequency, since is determined by the combined effect of the mechanical properties of the structures and the connected nerves sensitivity (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range)).

The ear (the external part of the hearing system) plays a focusing and enhancing role for some range of frequencies. It can be expected that its better resonance matches the hearing range, since it could explain its shape evolution as the result of improving the hearing capabilities of humans. But if you remove the ear, your range will be the same, maybe not as efficient, but should be the same.

So in summary, the ear affects the effectiveness of your hearing system, but does not determine the range. Although probably in evolution terms we could hypothesize its evolution is connected to its function of providing directional information and audio enhancement to the humans.

Comment: What about natural frequency of ear drum?